# how to 'chmod 777' serial port /dev/ttyACM0 on Ubuntu 16.04 on startup?

Tags: permissions, serial-port, ubuntu-16.04, tty

A number of blogs suggested that I should type `sudo adduser $USER dialout`, but it already showed that the `$USER` is already a member of the group `dialout`, and when I rebooted the computer, the `/dev/ttyACM0` was not given the read/write previlege.

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mar 22 13:53 /dev/ttyACM0
```

I am not familiar with Ubuntu 16.04, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should not make any file, especially a device file, world-writable on your machine. That's a huge security flaw. Group permission policies exist for a reason in the linux kernel. When your user really was a member of the `dialout` group, then you'd already have read and write permission on that file. Type `id` on the command line to list all the groups your user is in. Is `dialout` in that list? If not, then you have to add it. `sudo adduser $USER dialout` should be fine to add `$USER` to `dialout` group, but this is a Ubuntu-specific wrapper, the correct way to do add your user to `dialout` group on linux would be `sudo usermod -aG $USER dialout`. Check if that works better. You can also try `cat /dev/ttyACM0` to see if your user really has read permission on that file, if it hadn`t, you`d get a `Permission denied` error.

If your user is member of the `dialout` group, but your application still can't access that device, then make sure your application is really run as your user, or not as another user because of e.g. a startup script. Also make sure that it's really that file that is blocking your application from working and not something else. You'd need to provide further information for that matter.